# What is the negation of the statement "Every odd nmber is divisible by 2".

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Intuitively,I think it is "no odd number is divisible by 2" or it could be "every odd number is not divisible by 2". Is this a trivial question or is there more to it? What is the correct answer? BTW it is from a text i am reading.

Comment: There is an odd number that is not divisible by 2: if you find *one* case where a statement is false, it can't be true for all.

Comment: What an odd question!

Comment: I read the statement logically as "Odd $\Rightarrow$ divisible by 2" which would mean the negation is Not odd $\Rightarrow$ not divisible by 2". Weird though...

Comment: @MichaelChirico: That's not right. The negation of $P \implies Q$ is not $\lnot P \implies \lnot Q$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that you wanted to prove to someone that the statement *no odd number is divisible by* $2$ is false; what would you have to do? You’d have to show that some odd number actually *is* divisible by $2$. That is exactly what it means to say that the original statement is false. Thus, its negation is

> there is an odd number that is divisible by $2$.

All it takes is one such counterexample to contradict the original statement; it’s not necessary that *all* odd numbers be divisible by $2$ in order to have that contradiction.

**Added:** You’re starting from *every odd number is divisible by* $2$, so the details are different, but the principle is the same. To show that it’s false, you’d have to show that there is an odd number that is ... what?

Comment: I got a couple of conflicting and confusing answers. Also, doesn't the fact that there are no odd numbers divisible by 2 matter when answering the question? Can the negation of the false original statement also false? Please clarify if possible.

Comment: @Aditya: I’m sorry: I didn’t make it clear that I was working a similar problem rather than the one in your question. I’ve added to my answer to make that clear. In the problem that I solved, I started with a true statement and as its negation got a false one. In your problem you’re starting with a false statement, so the negation will of course be a true statement.

Answer (score 1):

The negation will be "There is at least one odd number not divisible by 2".  Note that the given statement is false assuming any counterexample, so saying all odd numbers are counterexamples is overkill.

Comment: “Not divisible”?

Answer (score 1):

"Not every odd number is divisible by $2$" or "Some odd number is not divisible by $2$". These equivalent statements, while true, are absurdly weak; and you can obviously say something much stronger; but they are literally the negation of the original (false) statement.